# How to get the charset of the message (using imap with php)

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, imap

How to get the charset of the message (using imap with php)

Answer (score 0):

Either check the mime headers or just go down the http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php route. That way you'll be damn sure everything you get is UTF-8

Comment: imap_utf8() decodes RFC2047-encoded headers but doesn't help with message bodies.

Comment: Actually, that's not true, in that it decodes RFC2047-encoded STRINGS whatever their role might be.


This guy: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php#102081 points in the right direction.

Your other option (and a puny one at that) is checking if your mail agent got its MIME bodies content types right. Mines tend to say stuff like: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Comment: All MIME bodies I've extracted from abusing a class I wrote for a previous question I had carried some variation of this: =?iso-8859-8?b?7eXs+SDv4SDp7Oj08A==?= which the RFC calls encoded-words. I gather they're not supposed to work that way or whatever, but still. I understand it to be anecdotal experience, but it's still a big corpus of it.

Comment: Come to think of it, you could also mb_detect_encoding($raw_mail, 'auto');

Right?

Comment: @Carlos: Your class is imposing that encoding on the message part content. Trust me on this. I write mail servers for a living. Or don't trust me and read [RFC 2045](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-6).

Answer (score -2):

You should use the function imap_headerinfo() and then look for the "charset" or even "Content-Type" using a simple search.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php

Comment: The docs you linked don't include either **charset** or **Content-Type** in the returned values.